# Distribute an array of values to another array of values

Tags: javascript, logic

I have a logic problem. I need to distribute an array of values evenly to another array of values. To illustrate:

```js
const colors = ['green', 'yellow', 'red']
const plots = [0, 10, 40, 90, 150, 230, 250]

const withColors = plots.map(e => ({
  value: e, color: ???
}))

/* expected output:
[
{value: 0, color: 'green'},
{value: 10, color: 'green'},
{value: 40, color: 'yellow'},
{value: 90, color: 'yellow'},
{value: 150, color: 'red'},
{value: 230, color: 'red'},
{value: 250, color: 'red'},
]
*/
```

current solution, I definitely have no idea yet, and I will update my question as I am currently brainstorming how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Can't see any logic behind this how this pattern will grow in future, but certainly you can try something like below.

```js
// const colors = ['green', 'yellow', 'red']
const plots = [0, 10, 40, 90, 150, 230, 250]

function getColors(val) {
     if(val >= 150 && val <=250) return "red";
     if(val >= 40 && val <= 90) return "yellow";
     return "green"
}

const withColors = plots.map(e => ({
  value: e, color: getColors(e)
}))
```

Comment: good try, but what we need is to distribute the colors evenly to the plots regardless of what the values are.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a brute force method where I iterate through the array and give each third of the plots a color.

Another way would be to write a helper function that handles turning the values of i/plots.length into 0, 1, or 2 and return that.

```
const colors = ['green', 'yellow', 'red'];
const plots = [0, 10, 40, 90, 150, 230, 250];

const result = {};

for (var i=0; i<plots.length; i++) {
  var thisPlot = plots[i];
  if (i / plots.length < 1/3.0) {
    result[thisPlot] = colors[0];
  }
  else if (i / plots.length < 2/3.0) {
    result[thisPlot] = colors[1];
  }
  else {
    result[thisPlot] = colors[2];
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Assigning colors one by one to each index

This will spread colors evenly, and is the simplest algorithm, but does not keep the colors grouped as in your example.

```js
const colors = ['green', 'yellow', 'red']
const plots = [0, 10, 40, 90, 150, 230, 250, 260]

const withColors = plots.map((plot, i) => ({ value: plot, color: colors[i % colors.length]}));

console.log(withColors);
```

### Keeping colors grouped

Just calculate the number of plots to map to each color, and assign each color to the appropriate number of plots.

One caveat: We require plots per color to be at least one in the case that there are less plots than colors. In this case, some colors will not be included.

There is one thing you haven't specified: what to do with the remainder. In your example `plots.length / colors.length == 7 / 3` is 2 with a remainder of 1. In other words, 2 plots per color, and 1 plot left over. Having a remainder of 1 is easy: just assign any color to an extra plot. But what about larger remainders? There's a few strategies.

### Assigning the last color to all trailing plots

Just round down plots per color and keep using the last color for any extra plots.

```js
const colors = ['green', 'yellow', 'red']
const plots = [0, 10, 40, 90, 150, 230, 250, 260]


const plotsPerColor = Math.max(1, Math.floor(plots.length / colors.length));
let colorIdx = 0;
let count = 0;

const withColors = plots.map((plot) => {
  const result = { value: plot, color: colors[colorIdx]};
  if (++count === plotsPerColor && colorIdx < colors.length-1) {
    colorIdx++;
    count = 0;
  }
  return result;
})

console.log(withColors);
```

### Spreading remainder evenly at end

Round down plots per color and increase it by one at the appropriate time.

```js
const colors = ['green', 'yellow', 'red']
const plots = [0, 10, 40, 90, 150, 230, 250, 260]


let plotsPerColor = Math.max(1, Math.floor(plots.length / colors.length));
let remainder = plots.length % colors.length;
let colorIdx = 0;
let count = 0;

const withColors = plots.map((plot) => {
  const result = { value: plot, color: colors[colorIdx]};
  if (++count === plotsPerColor) {
    if (++colorIdx === colors.length - remainder) plotsPerColor++;
    count = 0;
  }
  return result;
});

console.log(withColors);
```

### Spreading remainder evenly at beginning

Round up plots per color and decrease it by one at the appropriate time.

```js
const colors = ['green', 'yellow', 'red']
const plots = [0, 10, 40, 90, 150, 230, 250, 260]


let plotsPerColor = Math.ceil(plots.length / colors.length);
let remainder = plots.length % colors.length;
let colorIdx = 0;
let count = 0;

const withColors = plots.map((plot) => {
  const result = { value: plot, color: colors[colorIdx]};
  if (++count === plotsPerColor) {
    if (++colorIdx === remainder) plotsPerColor--;
    count = 0;
  }
  return result;
});

console.log(withColors);
```